# I want to redirect to the login screen when I try to access the screen after login when I am not logged in

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase-authentication

↓Error Message

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Infinite redirect in navigation guard　at eval
```

↓main.js

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store/store'
import firebase from 'firebase';
import config from './firebase.config';

firebase.initializeApp(config);

const app = createApp(App); app.use(router); app.use(store); app.mount('#app');

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.path === '/home') {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if (user) {
                next('/home')
            } else {
                next('/')
            }
        })
    } else {
        next();
    } });
```

↓router.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import Login from './components/Login';
import SignUp from './components/SignUp';
import Home from './components/Home';

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [
        { path: '/', component: Login }, //Login screen path
        { path: '/signup', component: SignUp }, //New registration screen path
        { path: '/home', component: Home }, //Screen path after login
    ],
});

export default router;
```

As mentioned above, I tried to write my own code, but it doesn't work very well.
Is it better to prepare a separate flag instead of checking the user information with　onAuthStateChanged?
I would appreciate it if you could teach me ‍♂️

Comment: How about changing ```next('/home')``` to ```next()```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `next('/home')` to `next()`

Reason: If you use `next('/home')`, below code would be run again and make a infinite loop

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.path === '/home') {
// this would be running again
...

}
```

Comment: It's done! Thank you ‍♂️ Why does it behave like this? I would appreciate it if you could tell me in detail. Also, if I am logged in and try to go to the login screen forcibly, how can I go to the screen after login?

Comment: else if (to.path === '/') { 
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => 
{ if (user) { 
　　next('/home') 
} else { next() } }) }

Comment: Question: if you are logged in and how to go to the login screen forcibly
Answer: redirect to ```/``` (or write a path for login, for example ```/login```, and sign the user out ```firebase.auth().signOut()```

Comment: Question: How can I manually rewrite the URL path when I am logged in and move to the screen after logging in when I try to go to the login screen?

Comment: I dont quite understand your question. I assume you are asking for the use case when user click on button 'log out', then it will navigate to login screen. Please refer this: https://michaelnthiessen.com/redirect-in-vue/. In your routes (in router.js) write one more route: ```{
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: Login,
    }```. Then, when user click on buton 'log out', use ```this.$router.push('login')``` to navigate.

Comment: I'm sorry. It is solved.
Thank you for answering. I'm very happy 